# Replace N/A or 0 with blank in VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I want to replace every N/A or 0 with a blank after executing VLOOKUP.

```
Dim myLastRow As Long

ActiveSheet.UsedRange

myLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)),"",IF(VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & myLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This does not work for me, I'm getting an error, but I don't know what exactly is wrong.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)"
```

does work, but the conditional function does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to put `""` between `""`. Replace all `""` with `""""`

`ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(C[-16],Blad1!C[-16]:C[6],17,FALSE)))"`